# SQL Query for network information

Tags: sql, database, networking, social-networking

I have a network with 14 nodes. (say 1 -14)
I am not sure how to show the network, but I can provide the database table which has the network information. The network information is as follows:

```
Nodes   Connected to the nodes
1            2,5
2           1,3,4,5
3            2,4
4           2,3,5
5           1,2,4
6           5,11,12
7           4,8,9
8             7
9           4,7,10,14
10            9,11
11            6,10
12            6,13
13           12,14
14           9,13
```

Now, in this case I need the information of all nodes present 2 hops away from node-8(say suppose)

```
node 8 - node 7(First Hop)
node 7 - node 4,8,9(Second Hop)
```

So, the solution is " node4 and node9 are 2 hops away from node8.

Is there a SQL Query that would help in resolving this? It may not just be 2 hops all the time. Given a question as 3 hops, we need to further our step as:

node4,8,9 is connected to  2,3,5,7,4,10,14

So, the solution is 2,3,5,7,10,14 (we excluded 4 because it is already 2 hops away from node8, we would consider shortest path) are 3 hops away from node8.

Is there a SQL query that could handle this situation for the above table?
Please let me know if I am not clear about anything?

Comment: Do you really want to do this in SQL ?

Comment: @Anamika: helped in the solution, or there is still an open question in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [on sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f527e/27/0)

Schema:

```
create table tNodes (
  id int
  ,connectedto int
)

insert tNodes values(1,2)
insert tNodes values(1,5)
insert tNodes values(2,1)
insert tNodes values(2,3)
insert tNodes values(2,4)
insert tNodes values(2,5)
insert tNodes values(3,2)
insert tNodes values(3,4)
insert tNodes values(4,2)
insert tNodes values(4,3)
insert tNodes values(4,5)
insert tNodes values(5,1)
insert tNodes values(5,2)
insert tNodes values(5,4)
insert tNodes values(6,5)
insert tNodes values(6,11)
insert tNodes values(6,12)
insert tNodes values(7,4)
insert tNodes values(7,8)
insert tNodes values(7,9)
insert tNodes values(8,7)
insert tNodes values(9,4)
insert tNodes values(9,7)
insert tNodes values(9,10)
insert tNodes values(9,14)
insert tNodes values(10,9)
insert tNodes values(10,11)
insert tNodes values(11,6)
insert tNodes values(11,10)
insert tNodes values(12,6)
insert tNodes values(12,13)
insert tNodes values(13,12)
insert tNodes values(13,14)
insert tNodes values(14,9)
insert tNodes values(14,13)
```

Query:

```
declare @id int = 8
declare @iHops int = 3
declare @iCnt int = 0

create table #tf (id int)
create table #tf0 (id int)
create table #tt (id int)

insert #tf values (@id)

while @iCnt<@iHops
begin

insert
    #tt (id)
  select distinct
    connectedto
  from
    tNodes
  where
    id in (select id from #tf)
    and
    connectedto not in (select id from #tf0)

  delete #tf
  insert #tf (id) select id from #tt
  insert #tf0 (id) select id from #tt
  delete #tt

  set @iCnt = @iCnt + 1
end

/*
select * from #tt
union all
select -1
union all
*/
select * from #tf
/*
union all
select -1
union all
select * from #tf0
*/
drop table #tf0
drop table #tf
drop table #tt
```

and the result:

```
ID
2
3
5
10
14
```

because the 4 and 7 also been included. (7 is 1 hop away, 4 is 2 hop away from 8).